# Sliding border working inside block container but not inside grid container

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code with this question in mind: **Why is it that the sliding border works in the **Block container** but not the Grid container?**

And: **How can one achieved the same sliding border but inside a Grid container?**

Note: I am using `<span>` because I cannot use pseudo elements on `<input>`.

```css
/* set different display types */

.blockContainer {
  display: block;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "areaOne";
}


/* make things tidier */

.blockContainer,
.gridContainer {
  width: fit-content;
}


/* provide sliding border to both inputs */

#inputInsideBlock,
#inputInsideGrid {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#inputInsideBlock+span:after,
#inputInsideGrid+span:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

#inputInsideBlock:hover+span:after,
#inputInsideBlock:hover+span:after {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockContainer">
  <input id="inputInsideBlock" type="text" placeholder="input inside block container"><span></span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="gridContainer">
  <input id="inputInsideGrid" type="text" placeholder="input inside grid container"><span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just miswrote your last css selector as `#inputInsideBlock` twice instead of `#inputInsideBlock` and `#inputInsideGrid`. It works fine once that is fixed.

```css
/* set different different display types */

.blockContainer {
  display: block;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "areaOne";
}


/* make things tidier */

.blockContainer,
.gridContainer {
  width: fit-content;
}


/* provide sliding border to both inputs */

#inputInsideBlock,
#inputInsideGrid {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#inputInsideBlock+span:after,
#inputInsideGrid+span:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

#inputInsideBlock:hover+span:after,
#inputInsideGrid:hover+span:after {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockContainer">
  <input id="inputInsideBlock" type="text" placeholder="input inside block container"><span></span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="gridContainer">
  <input id="inputInsideGrid" type="text" placeholder="input inside grid container"><span></span>
</div>
```